Use of the data from sites like NASDAQ and others
I am designing a site to publish some insights about big companies, their financial reports that I need to scrape from other website like NASDAQ, Bezinga etc. Is this allowed to publish this data in my personal website?

This might be a better question for the legal stack.

Facts cannot be copyrighted, but collections of facts can be and often are. License agreements, including ones phrased as "by using this site, you agree..." are also enforceable. Such sites are also generally marked as not available for web search.
Also, note that it is typical for such sites to monitor and restrict network traffic, and for them to inject minor "smoking gun" errors into their data so they can prove that you did, in fact, retrieve it from them.
So no, you can't make a business out of scraping their data and reselling it. You could probably write articles which include links to individual pages as supporting documentation, or quote individual data points, but bulk download is going to require paying whatever (high) price they ask for that kind of access.
